# Is it possible to start a parachain from block number greater than 1?

Tags: parachain, relay-chain

Basically I am asking if we can slot in an existing parachain that has been running for sometime, so has a few hundred blocks into a relay chain like kusama/polkadot. I know the relay chain requires the genesis hash and the wasm runtime as per-requisites before on-boarding a parachain, so in my mind, it doesn't matter if the block number starts from >> 0 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is possible to set the genesis block number to non-zero value?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7015/is-possible-to-set-the-genesis-block-number-to-non-zero-value)

Comment: So if I understand correctly, @AurevoirXavier that answer says that a lot of code depends on genesis == blocknum 0 so the answer is no? Which code? the relay chain code?

Answer (score 1):

For instance, Frontier will initiate database creation beginning with the most recent block number, processing them in a sequence from back to forward until 0.

Similar logic patterns can be observed in GRANDPA or BABE, particularly in the consensus aspect. This will also have an impact on the implementation of light clients.

It is important to mention that many DApps commonly assume that the genesis block is set to 0, which they integrate into their business logic.

Comment: I see. So I guess in that case, a data migration is the only way to migrate a running parachain into a parachain slot.

Comment: I believe that is currently the only available option.  But I'm not 100% sure.